# I am looking for an app that allows me to use Ipad 3 and 4 as secondary displays for MacOS

Tags: macos, display, ipad

I am looking for a software that allows me to use 2 Ipads as secondary displays at the same time. I have a Macbook Pro 2019, an Ipad 3, and an Ipad 4. I know the Ipads are pretty old but I am looking to still use them if possible.

I was able to use YAM Display to connect one of them as a secondary monitor, but it does not work with 2 Ipads at the same time. I also checked Duet Display but it does not support multiple Ipads.

I am willing to pay for an app that allows multiple Ipads (needs to support Ipad 3 and 4).

Any ideas?